# Erro ao tentar executar um programa via "makefile" ou via IDE

Tags: c++, windows-10, mingw

Atualmente, sempre que tento executar um código (c++) eu recebo essa mensagem de erro:[image: Não foi possível localizar o ponto de entrada do procedimento _ZNKSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESalcEE7compareEPKc na biblioteca de vínculo dinâmico (aqui aparece o diretório do arquivo que estou tentando executar)]
Procurei em vários sites e achei que o erro pudesse estar no "Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable", mas já tentei reinstalá-lo e não adiantou. Como eu uso o compilador MinGW, também tentei reinstalá-lo, mas também não adiantou de nada.
Um tempo atrás eu conseguia executar códigos normalmente, não sei a partir de que ponto esse problema apareceu.
Eu utilizo o Windows 10 e estou usando a IDE Geany. Não acho que a IDE tenha algo a ver com o problema, uma vez que programas gerados via "makefile" também estão dando esse mesmo erro.

Comment: Essa é a mensagem de erro: Não foi possível localizar o ponto de entrada do procedimento _ZNKSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESalcEE7compareEPKc na biblioteca de vínculo dinâmico (aqui aparece o diretório do arquivo que estou tentando executar).

Comment: Outra coisa, ja adicionei o diretório do MinGW ao Path.

Comment: você pode editar a pergunta, adicionando as informações necessárias.

Comment: Tente compilar o programa com a flag `-static-libstdc++` ou coloque a MinGW/bin no PATH, aí a dll do runtime da STL vai linkar com o programa durante a execução.